# Как узнать код страны устройства без Sim

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Мне нужно узнать код страны в которой находится устройство на данный момент без сим-карты.

Я пробовал следующие варианты:

```
String locale = context.getResources().getConfiguration().locale.getCountry();
```

этот вариант возвращает язык установленный на устройстве

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String countryCodeValue = tm.getNetworkCountryIso();
```

Этот вариант возвращает код страны пользователя, если в устройстве есть сим карта и пустое значение (""), если ее нет.

Как мне узнать реальный код страны без дополнительных разрешений. Без GPS и использования обращений к серверу(по IP)

Возможно ли узнать код по сети wifi?
Прошу помощи, потому что сам разобраться не смог.

Comment: Не вы определяете страну, а телефон вам сообщает страну. Но телефон не знает страну, поэтому вы ничего не получаете в ответ. `context.getResources().getConfiguration().locale.getCountry();` - этот код даст вам страну, которую выбрал сам пользователь. Но если ничего не выбрано, то страну вы никак не узнаете.

Comment: Я вижу только один вариант - по геолокации устройства, если пользователь разрешит тогда узнаете его страну

Comment: Таки да, беглое гугление не даёт никаких вариантов получить страну по WiFi. Только из сотовой сети и геолокации.

Comment: Так же в теории вы можете узнать по айпи. Но для этого нужен доступ в интернет у юзера. Но если он использует впн то соответственно вы не получите правильную инфу

Comment: Вот, господа, весь трабл в том, что вы все правильно говорите. Я и сам это понимаю, но не могу использовать пермишены и обращения на сторонние серваки для анализа ip. Зараза, должен же быть способ